# How can I change SQL data order from rows to columns?

Tags: sql, asp-classic, ado

I have a snippet of code that writes the data alphabetically from a database *ACROSS 3 columns* on a web page.

Example:

```
a result   b result  c result
d result   e result  f result
g result   h result  i result
```

I need instead to display it *alphabetically DOWN the columns*, like this:

```
a result   d result  g result
b result   e result  h result
c result   f result  i result
```

Keeping in mind I have about 100 data results, it would display the first 1/3 in column one descending, then start a new column and continue, breaking it into 3 equal parts.

The code I have now that sorts across the rows is:

```
<% 
GL="<table width="+Z+"100%"+Z+"border=0 cellpadding=3 celspacing=3>"
sql="select * from guideDef order by guideDesc;"
rs.open sql,adoCon
colCount=0
do while not rs.eof
  colCount=(colCount+1) mod 3
  if colCount=1 then GL=GL+"<tr>" 
  GL=GL+"<td valign=middle id=menu1 width="+Z+"33%"+Z+">"+E 
  GL=GL+"<a href="+Z+"shop.asp?guide="+rs("guide")+"&city=Plantation"+Z+">"+E 
  GL=GL+rs("guideDesc")+"</a></td>" 
  if colCount=0 then GL=GL+"</tr>" 
  GL=GL+E
  rs.moveNext
loop
rs.close
if colCount=1 then GL=GL+"<td> </td><td> </td></tr>"+E
if colCount=2 then GL=GL+"<td> </td></tr>"+E
GL=GL+"</table>"
response.write GL
%>
```

Thanks in advance for any help. I don't write code, so I have tried for hours to change this without success.

Comment: I gave up on your code, but you need to insert some line breaks in there.

Comment: Fixed, sorry, new to this editor...mangled the code because I didn't read instructions.

Comment: @unknown: No problem, normally I would have done it for you, but I am just too busy today.

Comment: @TheJaffe I think I solved your problem. Please look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this code will solve your problem:

```
<%
Set rs     = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

adoCon.Open "your connection string here"

Const COLUMN_COUNT    = 3

Const adOpenStatic    = 3

sql = "SELECT guide, guideDesc FROM guideDef ORDER BY guideDesc;" 
rs.Open sql, adoCon, adOpenStatic

CellsRemain = rs.RecordCount Mod COLUMN_COUNT
RowCount    = (rs.RecordCount - CellsRemain) / COLUMN_COUNT

Response.Write "<div>Rendering " & rs.RecordCount & " records to a " & _
               COLUMN_COUNT & " x " & RowCount & " table with " & _
               CellsRemain & " stand-alone cells.</div>"

Response.Write "<table width=""100%"" border=""0"" cellpadding=""3"" celspacing=""3"">" & vbCrLf

done = 0
cell = 0
While done < rs.RecordCount
  Response.Write "<tr>"  & vbCrLf
  While cell < COLUMN_COUNT And done < rs.RecordCount
    cell      = cell + 1
    done      = done + 1
    guide     = "" & rs("guide")
    guideDesc = "" & rs("guideDesc")
    url       = "shop.asp?guide=" + Server.UrlEncode(guide) + "&city=Plantation"
    Response.Write "<td>"
    Response.Write "<a href=""" & Server.HtmlEncode(url) & """>"
    Response.Write Server.HtmlEncode(guideDesc)
    Response.Write "</td>"  & vbCrLf
    If cell < COLUMN_COUNT Then rs.Move RowCount
  Wend
  If done < rs.RecordCount Then 
    rs.Move -1 * ((COLUMN_COUNT - 1) * RowCount - 1)
    cell = 0
  Else
    While cell < COLUMN_COUNT
      Response.Write "<td>&nbsp;</td>" & vbCrLf
      cell = cell + 1
    Wend
  End If
  Response.Write "</tr>" & vbCrLf
Wend

Response.Write "</table>" & vbCrLf
%>
```

This renders your table the way you want it:

```
A  E  H
B  F  I
C  G  J
D
```

You can use the `COLUMN_COUNT` constant to control how many columns will be made. The algorithm flexibly adapts to that number.

What the code does is basically this:

1. open a static RecordSet object so we can jump around in it freely
2. calculate how many rows and columns we need to show all records
3. `<tr>`
4. jump down the RecordSet in `RowCount` steps, painting `<td>`s until `<tr>` is full
5. jump back to the record that's after the one we started with in step 4
6. `</tr>`
7. if there are still records left, go to step 3
8. render as many empty cells as we need to make the table well-formed
9. done.

Comment: http 500 error when I use this code, my database open code is:

adoCon.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("db/nte.mdb"

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur? And what is the error message?

Comment: when I try to load the asp page, it immediately goes 500 error.  If you would contact me directly at lee_u at hotmail.com, I could send you link and more.  Thanks so much so far.

Comment: I assume you use Internet Explorer. If so, switch off "friendly error messages" in advanced options so the actual error message is not hidden anymore.

Comment: @Tomalak - I googled my db string, and found the syntax was a bit different because it was called from a script other than this one...so I fixed it. Your code is perfect, and I am humbled that you took the time to write it for a total stranger.  I wish there was a compensation system here! Much thx

Answer (score 5):

Maybe a better solution is to leave the SQL as is and handle this in the application code rather than as a result of the query.

Comment: It's on a web page, I thought of that too...letting it sort to one column, but I couldn't figure out how to then break it up via some html.

Answer (score 1):

Look at using the PIVOT AND UNPIVOT commands.

Comment: He's not asking to pivot the data, at all. Read the question closely.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore all the answers about using crosstab, they aren't reading your question.

What I would do is get your results as a giant table and divide them into three different collections, then go though each row inserting item one from collection one, then collection two, then collection three, ect, until you have exhausted all three collections.

The other option would be to write code that would go down one column until one third of the results were used, then move on to the next column, but given the way HTML is ordered, that would be a little more difficult to write.

Comment: I don't know if it's against the rules, but is it allowed here to offer money for someone to write the code for you? I don't write code at all.  I understand it, and can understand the answers given here, but the actual implementation...not my forte.

Comment: Perhaps some one will contact you, but I would advise attempting this modification yourself. You just have to do a little house keeping before you begin drawing your tables, and we aren't talking about that much code.

Comment: Thanks, but my ability is not up to it.  I can look at code, understand it, even rearrange or edit.  But not much else yet!  Thanks for the point in the right direction though.

Comment: The three collection example sounds good! You'd need to know exactly how many total results, put 1/3 (approx.) in each bag, then while you're drawing table rows, pull 1 result from each bag. See if you can find examples of ArrayLists for .net or Vectors for java...

Comment: @tom.dietrich: You are right. I've misread the question and changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could divide the results up into 3 parts (if you know the row count). Print them as 3 separate tables within separate div elements. You could then float the div elements next to each other using CSS.

if this sounds like what you want to do, (since you say you don't write code) let me know  if you need help with this.

Comment: That sounds feasible, but I do not know how to do that no.  It's a simple asp page with just the code above in it, and a css of course.

Comment: This was going to be my suggestion too: <div class="col">...1st third of results...</div><div class="col">...2nd third...</div><div class="col">...3rd third...</div> and CSS: .col { float:left;width:33%; }

Answer (score 0):

This is also referred to as crosstab queries. You need to use a case statement with some aggregate function see here

http://www.paragoncorporation.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?ArticleID=25

Comment: In other words, pivot and unpivot?

Comment: @mxc: *lol* That nails it. It's a bit strange that the SQL Server guys decided to use the word, in spite of the fact.

Answer (score 0):

something like this would be what I would do (in c#):

```
const int columns = 3;
string[] cells = GetCells(); // load your sql into this
string ret = "<table>";
int numRows = (cells.Length + columns - 1) / columns; // round up
for (int y = 0; y < numRows; y++)
{
    ret += "<tr>";
    for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
    {
        int elem = x*numRows + y;
        if (elem < cells.Length)
            ret += "<td>" + cells[elem] + "</td>";
        else
            ret += "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    }
    ret += "</tr>";
}
ret += "</table>";
```

and GetCells() would look something like:

```
string[] GetCells()
{
    string sql = "SELECT guide, guideDesc FROM guideDef ORDER BY guideDesc";
    rs.Open(sql, adoCon, adOpenStatic);
    string[] ret = new string[rs.RecordCount]
    for (int i=0; i<rs.RecordCount; i++)
    {
        ret[i] = "<a href=...></a>";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: great idea, but I do not know how to write sql into c#!

Comment: you wouldn't load the sql into c#, but load the data returned by your sql query into the single-dimensional array named rows.

Comment: could you write me an example?  I am as dense as a brick with this stuff.  I am amazed at the genius of people here...but you must remember I am a neophyte (and possibly semi-retarded).